# Constructing Isomorphism between $\langle \Bbb R, + \rangle$ and $\langle \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}, \times\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if it's possible to construct an isomorphism from the group of real numbers with addition to the group of nonzero real numbers with multiplication.  It doesn't seem like it should be.

Comment: There is, however, an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{>0}, \times)$ (namely, $x \mapsto e^x$).

Comment: How about between R×(Z/2Z) and (R∗,⋅)?  What would that sort of isomorphism even look like?

Comment: @Jen If you have another question, please ask it in a separate post, not in the comments for this one.

Comment: @Jen: Yes, $\mathbb{R}^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}/2$. I think you can figure this out.

Answer (score 9):

The group $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\times)$ has an element of order $2$, namely $-1$.  However, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ does not have an element of order $2$ (since $a+a=0$ implies $a=0$).